# How do i change a symfony form error message?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am using symfony 1.4.

I have a form like this:

**validator:**

```
$this->setValidator('name', new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true)));
```

**view:**

```
<?php echo $form['name']->renderError() ?>
```

How do i change the default "required" error message to, for example, "This field is required" ?

**Edit:** Also, how do i get rid of `<ul>` and `<li>` tags generated by the `renderError()`. method ? I just want the text to be displayed, no additional markup.

---

*Note:* This is an obvious question, but since I took a long time to find out, i think the question diserves to be asked here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.Change the required message:

```
new sfValidatorString(
    array(
        'required' => true,
    ), 
    array(
        'required'=>'You custom required message'
    ));
```

2.Create a new formatter class.

3.Redefine the attribute you want.

```
<?php
class myWidgetFormSchemaFormatter extends sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter
{

  protected
    $rowFormat                 = '',
    $helpFormat                = '%help%',
    $errorRowFormat            = '%errors%',
    $errorListFormatInARow     = "  <ul class=\"error_list\">\n%errors%  </ul>\n",
    $errorRowFormatInARow      = "    <li>%error%</li>\n",
    $namedErrorRowFormatInARow = "    <li>%name%: %error%</li>\n",
    $decoratorFormat           = '',
    $widgetSchema              = null,
    $translationCatalogue      = null;
```

4.In the configure method of your symfony form add

```
$oDecorator = new myWidgetFormSchemaFormatter($this->getWidgetSchema());
$this->getWidgetSchema()->addFormFormatter('myCustom', $oDecorator);
$this->getWidgetSchema()->setFormFormatterName('myCustom');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true), array('required'=>'This field is required'))
```

And you can create a custom WidgetFormSchemaFormatter by extending sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter to format your form output.